# How to multiple two values of type driver.Value

Tags: go, types, multiplication

I have two variables, both are of type driver.Value, is there a way to multiply them?

This is a very primitive example:

```
var a driver.Value
var b driver.value
result := a*b
```

but getting an error like `invalid operation: operator * not defined on a (variable of type driver.Value)`

Do I need to convert it to a float or a different type in order to do this?

Comment: what is a `driver.Value`? It's obviously not a primitive numeric type, so would need conversion or a method to do multiplcation.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql/driver#Value), driver.Value can be one of many types.

So first you need to assert the type you're expecting, then do your multiplication.

```
var a driver.Value
var b driver.value

aF := a.(float64)
bF := b.(float64)

result := aF*bF
```